# How to set the edge color of polygon patch in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I managed to render a polygon patch onto a matplotlib canvas.

In  the code below `node_coods` is a Nx2 numpy array containing a vertices of polygon.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

polygon = Polygon(node_coods, closed=True, edgecolor='r')
patches = [polygon]
p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=mpl.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)
ax.add_collection(p)
```

At present my plot looks like this, notice it does not have edge color, inspite of passing the argument as given in [manual](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html). How do I set the edge color of the polygon patch? I would like to set it to red, (but I'd like to have it tunable to any RGB  value later)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do

```
p = PatchCollection(patches,  alpha=0.4)
```

per the documentation, `edgecolors` is default to `None`, which got override by
`matplotlib.rcParams` default settings, which is transparent. So either do:

```
p = PatchCollection(patches, edgecolor='r', alpha=0.4)
ax.add_collection(p)
```

which gives

[image]

Or just use `add_patch`:

```
polygon = Polygon(node_coods, closed=True, edgecolor='r')
# patches = [polygon]
# p = PatchCollection(patches,  alpha=0.4)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(polygon)
```

which gives:

[image]